# Change editor color scheme in nitrous.io

Tags: ide, nitrousio

I don't see a way to change the color scheme in the nitrous.io editor but the white code text is a little harsh on my eyes.

How do I change the color scheme in the nitrous.io editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a way to change the color scheme at this time. If you are looking to use a text editor with your own customizations then take a look at [Nitrous Desktop](http://www.nitrous.io/desktop). With the desktop app you will be able to sync locally and use a text editor such as [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/).